# Inline-block element becomes block level element with my code, how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want my span tag to move dynamicly with respect to time when i click the "Try" Button. It works perfectly but when i click it, the span tag starts to display as a block element, it encompasses the whole right block level but left. I just want it to display like it's initial figure. How can i solve this ?

My code :

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var j = 0;
        var i = 0;
        function myFunction2() {
            document.getElementById("demo").style.left = j + "px";
            document.getElementById("demo").style.top = j + "px";
            j++;
        }

        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").style.right = "0px";
            j = 0;
            i = 0;
            while (i <= 250) {
                setTimeout(myFunction2, (i**2)*0.01);
                i++;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <span id="demo" style="position:absolute;left:text-align:center;0px;top:0px;font-size:30px;background-color:powderblue;border:1px solid powderblue;border-radius: 3px;padding: 10px;">Shift</span><br>
    <button id="submit" type="button" onclick="myFunction();" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 20px;">Try</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nothing suggests that `<span>` changed `display` to `block`. It's `position:absolute;`, and it's `.style.top` and `.style.left` are changing. The code works as expected. In other words, unless you explain your desired results more accurately, you probably won't get a reliable answer.

Comment: Yes, code works properly. I think i messed the script a little bit and couldn't get out of it, but i fixed it through the comment below. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, span is actually `inline` from the beginning and you are not setting it anywhere to be `inline-block`. What happens here is that you have a `left` and `right`, so you tell it to start from the left value and end at the right value. You would have to check what you really want to do with your animation there?

Comment: Actually, the span has `position:absolute` which will make it behave like a block level element, not an inline element (although that is its initial display value).

Comment: @agrm `display` is not `position`. You cannot set a height on an `inline` Element, while you can on `inline-block`.

Comment: @StackSlave I agree to the fact that _display isn't position_. My point is that _position will affect display_. The span in question isn't inline. It is rendered as a block level element. Even if you would explicitly set `display:inline` it would still be rendered as a block level element as long as you apply `position:absolute`. It's browser behaviour. See for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/5uy0thvf/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you wanted to see:

```js
let j = 0;
let i = 0;

const demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
const button = document.querySelector('#btn');

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.left = j + "px";
  document.getElementById("demo").style.top = j + "px";
  if (++j > 250) {
    button.disabled = false;
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  button.disabled = true;
  demo.classList.remove('animate');
  j = 0;
  i = 0;
  while (i <= 250) {
    setTimeout(myFunction2, (i**2)*0.01);
    i++;
  }
}

function raf(init = false) {
  demo.classList.remove('animate');
  if (init) {
    j = i = 0;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    let cnt = 0;

    const newVal = `${j++}px`;
    demo.style.left = demo.style.top = newVal;
    j <= 250 && raf();
  });
}

function cssAnimate() {
  demo.style.left = demo.style.top = 0;
  demo.classList.toggle('animate');
}
```

```css
#demo {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: powderblue;
  border: 1px solid powderblue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: none;
}
#demo.animate {
  transition-delay: 1s;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  transform: translateX(250px) translateY(250px);
}

.submit {
  position: relative; 
  top: 60px; 
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span id="demo">Shift</span><br>
<button class="submit" id="btn" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
<button class="submit" type="button" onclick="raf(true)">Try RAF (without easing)</button>
<button class="submit" type="button" onclick="cssAnimate()">CSS animate</button>
```

You have some typos in your inline style:

```
position:absolute;left:text-align:center;0px;
```

should be:

```
position: absolute; text-align: center; left: 0px;
```

then, in `myFunction()` you add `right: 0px;` and also in `myFunction2()` you add 'left: 0px;' and inrease this left value in the `while` loop. This 2 styles stretch your inline span between those 2 values (right: 0 and variable left). To fix it, just remove

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.right = "0px";
```

line from `myFunction()`.

Some suggestions:

- use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) (RAF) instead of `setTimeout` for animation. RAF is executed just before browser rerender (approximately 60 times per second), while `setTimeout` may be executed ~250 times per second and ~75% of its code will not affect animation
- use CSS file / section, instead of massive inline style, which is harder to read and test
- use `translate: transformX()` instead of `position: absolute;`, which is cheaper in terms of browser performance ([some info](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count) by Google)

I added RAF and CSS only examples.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i fixed it. I think i messed up something in my code.

Comment: can i ask one more thing ? When i click the button multiple times in a row, the block goes over my desired destination. As i click more rapidly, it goes further. How can i fix it ?

Comment: one solution would be disable button while the block is in animation process. I added this to my answer (look for `button.disabled = true;` in my code)